# How to create a MySQL stored procedure from PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

My attempts to query MySQL from PHP with a create statement of a store procedure (SP) have all failed. Is this not possible ?

If indeed possible, please give an example.

Comment: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?98,161275,161275

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MySQL manual has a clear overview about [how to create stored procedures (*13.1.15. `CREATE PROCEDURE` and `CREATE FUNCTION` Syntax*)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-procedure.html).

The next question is: does the account you use to access the MySQL database the propper rights to actually create a procedure?

Details about this question can be found here: [*19.2.2. Stored Routines and MySQL Privileges*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/stored-routines-privileges.html)

Answer (score 3):

Besides of the privileges, what quite probably might cause your problem is, that actually mysql_query($query) can only work one command per call !

So what you have to do is to split up the commands into sevaral mysql_query($query) -calls.

What i mean is something like this:

```
$query = "DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS fnElfProef (accountNr INT)";

mysql_query($query);

$query = "CREATE FUNCTION fnElfProef (accountNr INT)
    RETURNS BOOLEAN
       BEGIN
          DECLARE i, totaal INT DEFAULT 0;
          WHILE i < 9 DO
             SET i = i+1;
             SET totaal = totaal+(i*(accountNr%10));
             SET accountNr = FLOOR(accountNr/10);
          END WHILE;
       RETURN (totaal%11) = 0;
    END";
mysql_query($query);


$query = "SELECT * FROM mytable";
mysql_query($query);
```

Answer (score 2):

As long as:

- You're using MySQL 5.0+
- Your account has been authorized for creating stored procedure
- You're using the valid [CREATE PROCEDURE syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html)

Then it should be working. Check these and get back to us.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the DELIMITER statement from within PHP. Therefore,

```
1) remove the DELIMITER statements
2)and change all your delimiters to ;
```

It is annoying because now you have to have a version with DELIMITERS for development and testing in MySQL command line or a MySQL tool like sqlyog or MySQL workbench, and a version without DELIMITERS to use via your PHP program.

If someone knows a better way, I'd like to hear it - (but not by calling a OS shell script - that has too many residual issues.)

And you need SUPER permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Have you got sufficient privileges on the account you are connecting from PHP with? From [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html)

> As of MySQL 5.0.3, to execute the
>   CREATE PROCEDURE or CREATE FUNCTION
>   statement, it is necessary to have the
>   CREATE ROUTINE privilege

See also [Stored Routines and MySQL Privileges](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-routines-privileges.html) in the manual.

Answer (score 0):

Replace
mysql_query($query);

To
mysql_unbuffered_query($query,$link_connection);